# Can we obtain topology results using analysis in metric measures spaces?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth compact manifold. It is known that a lower bound on the Ricci curvature is equivalent to the convexity of the entropy on $\mathcal{P}^2(M)$ (Von Rennesse and Sturm '05), but I don't known whether there is any paper that using this result, and maybe another condition on $M$, that obtain a topological result about $M$.

On the other hand, is there any similar result for the scalar curvature?, sometime I've heard that a lower bound on the scalar curvature is easier to treat than a lower bound on the Ricci curvature but I don't know why, if anybody could help me to understand this it would be very helpful.

Comment: For example, can we obtain Bonnet-Myers theorem just using the convexity of the entropy on $\mathcal{P}^2(M)$?. By analogous I mean similar.

Comment: Have you read the papers by Sturm http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s11511-006-0002-8 http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s11511-006-0003-7 and by Lott and Villani http://dx.doi.org/10.4007/annals.2009.169.903 ?

Comment: It is not so easy to answer your question. We do have Bonnet-Myers in CD(K,N) spaces, but here the convexity-type condition is using the Rényi entropy and not the Shannon entropy.

Comment: I have not yet read the papers you mentioned above but I'm studying a course of Nicola Gigli on the subject, I will read those papers very soon. Do you have the reference of Bonnet-Myers in $CD(K,N)$?

Comment: On the other hand, is there a link between $c$-cyclically monotone sets (from optimal transport theory) and rectifiability?

Comment: The proof for Bonnet-Myers you can find from the second paper by Sturm, for instance. Gigli might visit all such results during the course (depending how long the course is). If you want to read the basic stuff by yourself, I would suggest Villani's book: Optimal transport, old and new. Luckily it is freely available online http://cedricvillani.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/preprint-1.pdf